# how do I keep one metismenu selection active when another metismenu is selected?

Tags: jquery

I'm using metismenu but not for links but just for form choices. The two menus "Trial" and "Type" are independent, so I should be able to retain choices in one menu while selecting items form another. For example I would like "Events > Endothelial" and "Type > Sample" to both be highlighted.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#assay').metisMenu(
    {preventDefault: true}
    );
  $('#tubetype').metisMenu(
     {preventDefault: true}
    );
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/2.7.0/metisMenu.min.css');
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/2.7.0/metisMenu.min.css");
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.6.0/themes/prism.min.css");
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css");
  
.sidebar-nav {
    background: #212529;
}
.sidebar-nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #343a40;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu {
    background: #212529;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu li + li {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu li:first-child {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.sidebar-nav .metismenu li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu > li {
/*    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
    flex: 1 1 0%;*/
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar-nav .metismenu a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 13px 15px;
    color: #adb5bd;
    outline-width: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu ul a {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu ul ul a {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 45px;
}

.sidebar-nav .metismenu a:hover,
.sidebar-nav .metismenu a:focus,
.sidebar-nav .metismenu a:active {
    color: #f8f9fa;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #0b7285;
}


.sidebar-nav h3  {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 13px 15px;
    color: #adb5bd;
    outline-width: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/2.7.0/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <nav class="sidebar-nav">
          <h3>Select a Trial and Assay</h3>
          <ul class="metismenu" id="assay">
            <li>
              <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false">Events</a>
              <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                <li><a href="#">EV</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Endothelial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Count</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">T-cell</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false">LVAD</a>
              <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                <li><a href="#">EV</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <h3>Select tube class</h3>
          <ul class="metismenu" id="tubetype">
            <li>
              <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false">Type</a>
              <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                <li><a href="#">Compensation control</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Negative control</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Quite lost. For what are you posting Lorem Ipsum... and so on...?

Comment: the stackoverflow constraints demand a certain text-to-code ratio that is unreasonable

Comment: Never listened before. We should scalate this requirement to SOF staff for avoiding it. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/k5Lnnqvx/1/

Answer (score 1):

instead of using metismenu, I wrote my own code to handle auto collapse using only bootstrap.

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sidebarMenu a").click(function (event) {
        showHideNavItem(this.dataset.target);
    });
});
function showHideNavItem(navId) {
    if (navId !== null) {
        var currentActiveNavId = navId;
        var listNav = $("#sidebarMenu li > a");
        for (var i = 0; i < listNav.length; i++) {
            if (listNav[i].dataset.target !== undefined && listNav[i].dataset.target !== currentActiveNavId) {
                var collapseId = listNav[i].dataset.target;
                $(collapseId).collapse("hide");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**html**

```
<ul id="sidebarMenu" class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">Dropdown 1</a>
      <ul id="demo1" class="collapse">
         <li>
            <a href="#">Dropdown Item 1-1</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Dropdown Item 1-2</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Dropdown 2</a>
      <ul id="demo2" class="collapse">
         <li>
            <a href="#">Dropdown Item 2-1</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Dropdown Item 2-2</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3">Dropdown 3</a>
      <ul id="demo3" class="collapse">
         <li>
            <a href="#">Dropdown Item 3-1</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Dropdown Item 3-2</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```